# Correct way to remove entry from a SQL table along with the relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If we have `TableA` and `TableB` related by `TableAB` where `TableAB` has foreign keys for the first two table, then what's the go-to way of deleting an entry from `TableA`? Up to now if used a property such as `IsActive` with a bit to describe if the entry is still valid. However, that makes it a little problematic when there are "ghost entries" in the relation tables, such as `TableAB`.

How should I proceed?

---

One chaining table in question.

```
CREATE TABLE EntradaContadorCliente (

    ClaveECC            int AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
    ClaveCliente        int not null,
    ClaveContador       int not null,
    ClaveEntrada        int not null,

    PRIMARY KEY (ClaveECC),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClaveCliente) REFERENCES Cliente(ClaveCliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClaveContador) REFERENCES Contador(ClaveContador),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClaveEntrada) REFERENCES EntradaBitacora(ClaveEntrada)

);
```

Comment: What database are you using? Normally you would have a foreign key with a `Cascade` delete, meaning any time the parent is deleted all child records are too, so that you don't end up with "orphans".

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Is there a default setting for this cascade deletion?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `TableA` and `TableB` related by `TableAB`; which means `TableAB` is a chaining table. One way is to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for cascading the delete operation on primary table.

Alternative is to, manually delete the entries from your chaining table once the entry has been deleted from primary table.

You can use a `ALTER` statement to re-create the FK constraint like

```
ALTER TABLE `TableAB` DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_KEY_Test;
ALTER TABLE `TableAB` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_KEY_Test FOREIGN KEY ('some_column') 
REFERENCES `TableA` ('Test_column1') ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

From [MySQL Documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> **CASCADE**: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported.

Comment: So if I delete an entry from `TableA` with the command `ON DELETE CASCADE` *every* chaining table will be updated?

Comment: Yes, that's what the option is for.

Comment: But it isn't set for cascading by default, right? I need to add the option for each table that requires it.

Comment: @OFRBG, Yes, you will have to. Check edit in answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

first you disable all foreign key with:-

```
 alter table table_name
 nocheck constraint fk_constraint
```

then you delete data in parent table.